# How to form a Gerrit search for reviews that have more than one +1 but pending a +2

Tags: gerrit

I'd like to search our Gerrit instance for reviews that have more than one +1 score but are still pending a +2?

Our review process is such that we need at least two +1 before going to approval phase, which is where the +2 would be given.

I've tried this query;

```
/?title=TF+Pending+Approval&Reviews=project:my/project is:open label:Code-Review>1
```

But that just seems to get the reviews that have a +2, and omits any that do have multiple +1s (and no +2).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that.

I think the following suggestion is not a useful option for you too (because I think you have several users involved, right?).

```
label:Code-Review=1,user1 AND label:Code-Review=1,user2
```

Another option is to write a script to query the changes using REST and then process the result.

Comment: Thanks, Marcelo. I suspected that this would be the case. And yes we have several reviewers, although there is only a single reviewer that give the +2 (currently). I'll try to see if excluding a +2 from him would work - AND NOT label:Code-Review=2, superuser1